# How do I open Facebook links with my webview app?

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a Webview app that is based on a news website. That news website has a facebook page where it shares various viral news from that website. Is it possible for me to do so that, when a facebook user clicks on a link in facebook, that it would have a selection to open the link in my Webview app, not only the browser?